# Text view not aligning to the guideline in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have the following  Constraint Layout:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/vertical_guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="2 hours ago" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/source_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/date_tv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/date_tv"
            tools:text="BBC News" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headline_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date_tv"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/vertical_guideline"
            tools:text="Apple admits slowing down older iphones" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>`
```

It has the following output:

[image: Layout output of the above code]

Now what I want is that the headline text view should only be as wide as the guideline and should move to the next line when the text is long. Which is not happening. Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem. But can you please explain a little bit more as to why this solution works? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try setting the width to `0dp` (`match_constraints`) as follows:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headline_tv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date_tv"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/vertical_guideline"
        tools:text="Apple admits slowing down older iphones" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using android:width=wrap_content for headline_tv which prioritizes the actually width of the textview. Use 0dp so it would match constraint.